# Idiomatically access an element of a vector mutably and immutably

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How would you mutate a vector in such a way where you would need an immutable reference to said vector to determine how you would need to mutate the vector? For example, I have a piece of code that looks something like this, and I want to duplicate the last element of the vector:

```
let mut vec: Vec<usize> = vec![123, 42, 10];
// Doesn't work of course:
vec.push(*vec.last().unwrap())
// Works, but is this necessary?
let x = *vec.last().unwrap();
vec.push(x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> immutable reference [...] to determine how you would need to mutate the vector?

The short answer is you don't. Any mutation to the vector could *possibly* invalidate all existing references, making any future operations access invalid data, potentially causing segfaults. Safe Rust doesn't allow for that possibility.

Your second example creates a **copy** of the value in the vector, so it no longer matters what happens to the vector; that value will continue to be valid.

What's unfortunate about the first example is that if you follow the order of operations, a human can tell that the immutable value is retrieved before the mutation happens. In fact, that's why the multiple-statement version is possible at all! This is indeed a current limitation of the Rust borrow checker. There is [investigation ongoing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811) to see if some of these types of limitations can be lifted.