# idiomatic mutable arena traversal dependent on immutable member

Tags: rust

How should I rewrite the following code idiomatically?

The problem seems to be that `traversal` could be modified during `action()`.  One solution would be to create a temporary copy of `traversal` inside of `traverse`, but that would be a burden if `traversal` is large.

Maybe [Idiomatically access an element of a vector mutably and immutably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544667/idiomatically-access-an-element-of-a-vector-mutably-and-immutably) is the canonical version of this, but I am not sure (and have not fully understood the referenced issue)?

```
struct Foo {}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn action(&mut self, foo_idx: usize) {
        // mutate self.arena[foo_idx]
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        for i in &self.traversal {
            self.action(*i);
        }
    }
}
```

current error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
14 |         for i in &self.traversal {
   |                  ---------------
   |                  |
   |                  immutable borrow occurs here
   |                  immutable borrow later used here
15 |             self.action(*i);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Does `action` only modify `self.arena[foo_idx]`?  You can change `action` so that it only takes a `&mut Foo` if that is the case.

Comment: it needs immutable access to more of self, but only mutates that specific `Foo` so in principle we could adjust the arguments to `action` to take all of the _other_ fields from `self` (let's assume there are actually some more) excluding `traversal` , I am hopeful there is a more elegant approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `Bar` has two apparently disjoint fields, so it should be possible to hold references to each of them at the same time. The problem, though, is even though `action` only touches `arena`, rust assesses the borrowing rules based on the function's prototype:

```
fn action(&mut self, foo_idx: usize)
```

which indicates that it takes a mutable borrow of self.

Here are a few possible solutions:

#### Inline

If the mutation being performed inside `action` is simple, and isn't called from anywhere else, then just do it inline inside `traverse`:

```rust
struct Foo {}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        for i in &self.traversal {
            // mutate arena here
            self.arena[*i] = Foo{};
        }
    }
}
```

#### Refactor

If `traversal` and `arena` are really two different things, maybe it makes more sense for them to belong to separate types, like this:

```rust
struct Foo {}

struct Baz(Vec<Foo>);

impl Baz {
    fn action(&mut self, foo_idx: usize) {
        self.0[foo_idx] = Foo{};
    }
}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Baz,
}

impl Bar {
    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        for i in &self.traversal {
            self.arena.action(*i);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Associated Function

A variation on the above theme is to simply change the prototype of `action` so that it takes only the field it will modify as input. `action` is no longer a method as such - it does not take `self` - but is still associated with the type `Bar`:

```rust
struct Foo {}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn action(arena: &mut Vec<Foo>, foo_idx: usize) {
        arena[foo_idx] = Foo{};
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        for i in &self.traversal {
            Self::action(&mut self.arena, *i);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Traverse via index

Instead of iterating the `traversal` Vec, you can avoid taking the initial immutable borrow like this:

```rust
struct Foo {}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn action(&mut self, foo_idx: usize) {
        // mutate self.arena[foo_idx]
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        for traversal_idx in 0..self.traversal.len() {
            let i = self.traversal[traversal_idx];
            self.action(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply.  Your "traverse via index" looks like the best fit for my needs.  The "associated function approach is what both @l-f and @poijo suggested, but becomes awkward when `self` actually has a bunch of other fields that `action` wants immutable access to (and the need for that, which I indicated in my comment response to @l-f seems to preclude your "refactor" approach, unless I am confused).

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this (plus an easier way that's less general). The first is to destructure the struct so you aren't dealing with `self` anymore, but only its data. Then the data are independent so you the ownership of `arena` and `traverse` won't conflict anymore because they are independent. The disadvantage is that the function parameters get more complex.

```
struct Foo {
    pub i: i32,
}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn action(arena: &mut Vec<Foo>, foo_idx: usize) {
        arena[foo_idx].i += 1;
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        let Bar { traversal, arena } = self;
        for i in traversal {
            Self::action(arena, *i);
        }
    }
}
```

The other way has a nicer API but is more risky: take just one value out of `self` (use `std::mem::take` or `std::mem::replace`) so you can reference it with no dependency on `self`. This is a liability is because you need to remember to put the value back in afterwards, and if you are using `Result`, `?` can make the function return early and not execute the cleanup.

```
struct Foo {
    pub i: i32,
}

struct Bar {
    traversal: Vec<usize>,
    arena: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn action(&mut self, foo_idx: usize) {
        self.arena[foo_idx].i += 1;
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        let traversal = std::mem::take(&mut self.traversal);
        for i in traversal.iter() {
            self.action(*i);
        }
        self.traversal = traversal;
    }
}
```

If your real code is only iterating as in this example, there is an easier way to solve it: change the vector to `Rc<Vec<Foo>>`. That way you can use `Rc::clone` to get a copy of the variable that's independent of `self`, but points at the same data.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply!  As I mentioned in my response to @l-f, your first approach did seem like the most general approach, but becomes uncomfortably verbose when `self` has multiple fields that are all immutably needed.  For your latter approach, unless I am confused, this would add non-trivial cognitive complexity and also runtime overhead to the `arena` which caused me to shy away.